# Pneumatics to mechanical

Tags: kinematics, momentum

Simply put it, i am trying to figure out how much momentum i can get on a crank axis based on simple pneumatic system such as this "[Car pump](https://www.kseal.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Water-Pump.jpg)".

What im thinking is that inertias aside, for a cylindrical object the

Effect=F **x** r * $\omega$ (Force x Distance * rpm)

And for a pneumatic system Effect is Q **x** P (Flow x Preasure)

What i am trying to do is to use a pump to put a solid cylinder in motion and i need to know the relation between the flow equation of pump and the momentum equations of the cylinder

Im guessing that these diffrent types of Effects are not equal each other (F**x**R =! Q**x**P) and thus my problem.

So my question is how dose one convert effect of the pump in the picture to "F **x** r * $\omega$"

Comment: How much momentum per unit time is lost by the air? Assuming no dissipation, this is equal to the momentum per unit time gained by the rotating body. (With dissipation, the above is the _maximum_ rate of momentum transfer.)

Comment: So you are saying that in a ideal system, FxR*$\omega$ = QxP ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest of ways i found was to use the preservation of momentum.

$F*r$ for the cylinder is equal to $P*r*A$ of the "pump" if air hiting the center of the fan blades